# Fork Join not working while using angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I have been using fork join in angular 9 but somehow stuck at this point.

Below is the code i am trying -->

```
 getMenuSubMenudata() {
  let menudata = this.getMenus();
   let subMenuData = this.getSubMenus();
    return forkJoin[ menudata, subMenuData ];
  }
```

but getting below error

```
<TS> Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
<TS> Type Observable<any> can not be used as an index type.
```

Could someone please suggest where to look at.

Thanks

Comment: You used square brackets rather than parathensis for your `forkJoin` function call : `forkJoin(menudata, subMenuData);` vs `forkJoin[ menudata, subMenuData ];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forkJoin is a function not a object, you need to pass the array of observables as a parameter.

```
return forkJoin([ menudata, subMenuData ]);
```

edit: Is going to depend which version of RXJS that you are using. Older versions use:

`forkJoin(menudata, subMenuData)` while newer version use `forkJoin([ menudata, subMenuData ])`

Angular 9 should be using the newer version by default